# How to write SQL query to log call centre actions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Table1
**History**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Callplacetime            | Finish Code         | Address   | Identidy                                
2018-09-26 16:29:08:000  | No Answer           | ABC       | 10                                  
2018-10-15 12:37:08:000  | Voicemail           | ABC       | 10                                 
2018-10-16 18:40:09:000  | No Answer           | ABC       | 10                                
2018-10-16 21:29:08:000  | No Answer           | ABC       | 10                                  
2018-10-19 04:57:10:000  | Appointment Booked  | ABC       | 10                                
2018-09-26 16:29:57:000  | No Answer           | XYZ       | 20                                 
2018-10-15 16:29:08:000  | Voicemail           | XYZ       | 20                                
2018-10-15 18:29:08:000  | Appointment Booked  | XYZ       | 20                                
2018-10-25 16:29:08:000  | Appointment Booked  | MNO       | 30
```

table2
**List**

```
---------------------------------------------
Address  |   Identity  
ABC      |   10
XYZ      |   20
MNO      |   30
```

I would like data to be shown as,

```
Callplacetime            | Finish Code         | Address   | Attempts by Agents
2018-09-26 16:29:08:000  | No Answer           | ABC       | Attemp1 
2018-10-15 12:37:08:000  | Voicemail           | ABC       | Attemp2
2018-10-16 18:40:09:000  | No Answer           | ABC       | Attemp3
2018-10-16 21:29:08:000  | No Answer           | ABC       | Attemp4  
2018-10-19 04:57:10:000  | Appointment Booked  | ABC       | Attemp5
2018-09-26 16:29:57:000  | No Answer           | XYZ       | Attemp1 
2018-10-15 16:29:08:000  | Voicemail           | XYZ       | Attemp2
2018-10-15 18:29:08:000  | Appointment Booked  | XYZ       | Attemp3
2018-10-25 16:29:08:000  | Appointment Booked  | MNO       | Attemp1
```

So basically agents call to the specific Addresses (customer). So if he calls only once to that Address so the Attempts by Agents column say Attempt1 if he calls same address second time then Attempt2 and so on. The Max Attempts an agent can do is 5 (five). The most recent "callplacetime", of course, would be the latest Attempt by an agent.

How can I write the query that is to add Attempts by Agent column as per the above scenario?

Comment: You did pretty decent for your first post, but [this post](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977) will help you avoid down votes in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do like

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([Callplacetime] datetime, [Finish Code] varchar(18), [Address] varchar(3), [Identidy] int)
;

INSERT INTO T
    ([Callplacetime], [Finish Code], [Address], [Identidy])
VALUES
    ('2018-09-26 16:29:08', 'No Answer', 'ABC', 10),
    ('2018-10-15 12:37:08', 'Voicemail', 'ABC', 10),
    ('2018-10-16 18:40:09', 'No Answer', 'ABC', 10),
    ('2018-10-16 21:29:08', 'No Answer', 'ABC', 10),
    ('2018-10-19 04:57:10', 'Appointment Booked', 'ABC', 10),
    ('2018-09-26 16:29:57', 'No Answer', 'XYZ', 20),
    ('2018-10-15 16:29:08', 'Voicemail', 'XYZ', 20),
    ('2018-10-15 18:29:08', 'Appointment Booked', 'XYZ', 20),
    ('2018-10-25 16:29:08', 'Appointment Booked', 'MNO', 30);

SELECT Callplacetime,
       [Finish Code],
       Address,
       'Attempt' + 
       CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Identidy ORDER BY Callplacetime) AS VARCHAR(10)) [Attempts by Agents]
FROM T;
```

**Returns:**

```
+---------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+
|    Callplacetime    |    Finish Code     | Address | Attempts by Agents |
+---------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+
| 26/09/2018 16:29:08 | No Answer          | ABC     | Attempt1           |
| 15/10/2018 12:37:08 | Voicemail          | ABC     | Attempt2           |
| 16/10/2018 18:40:09 | No Answer          | ABC     | Attempt3           |
| 16/10/2018 21:29:08 | No Answer          | ABC     | Attempt4           |
| 19/10/2018 04:57:10 | Appointment Booked | ABC     | Attempt5           |
| 26/09/2018 16:29:57 | No Answer          | XYZ     | Attempt1           |
| 15/10/2018 16:29:08 | Voicemail          | XYZ     | Attempt2           |
| 15/10/2018 18:29:08 | Appointment Booked | XYZ     | Attempt3           |
| 25/10/2018 16:29:08 | Appointment Booked | MNO     | Attempt1           |
+---------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+
```

---

Since your first table already hase the `Address` column, I don't see what is the purpos of the second table?

Comment: I think you want order by Callplacetime

Comment: the order is based on callplacetime. Since you inserted the data in this order it happened to work but this isn't guaranteed to stay the same. But if you [change the order of the insert you'll get different results... but Callplacetime will fix this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=03f723e5883c06d24cc52ff89f24b4e5).

Comment: I did, in the fiddle i sent you. Click that link. `15/10/2018 12:37:08 Voicemail` is attempt1. Then in the second query you will see how my query behaves correctly....

Comment: The order does matter... *if he calls same address second time then Attempt2 and so on* and your code doesn't result to this. Second time would be the second instance which is determined by the `Callplacetime` column. This isn't difficult

Answer (score 0):

You could use a window function and string concatenation.

```
select *, 
'Attempt' + cast(row_number() over (partition by Address order by Callplacetime) as varchar)
from [History]
```

As a side note, I'm not sure what the `List` table is for. I would expect you to need to join to it to get the `Address` based off the `Identity` in your `History` table... but you included it in the `History` table so I'm not sure what the ERD looks like here.

Comment: It's `Identidy` column not `IDENTITY`, and I think you should specify the length of the `VARCHAR` :)

Comment: Usually @Sami but casting doesn't default to varchar(8) like not specifying... `select cast(1231635416512316516516 as varchar)`. Also they had `Address` in the `History` table. And you are right about `Identity` but i'm sure that's a typo given the column name in `Lists`

Comment: @MohsinAli you are welcome, but you selected the answer which is incorrect. Just a heads up... you are going to run into issues unless Sami changes their query